# Replace QRadioButton's text with image

Tags: qt

I have two radio buttons. I'd like to replace the controls' text (not the indicator) with images/icons. How can I do this?

With a QLabel I do this by using `setPixmap();` the method is not available in **QRadioButtons**.

I tried

```
setStyleSheet("background-image: url(./images/img.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;");
```

but the image is set as the background of the entire control (indicator + label), not just the label.

Any idea?

Comment: you can remove its text and put one label near it.

Comment: That's so obvious yet so clever :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use ***Qt resource system*** to add the desired icons and then use the buttons `setIcon` method to assign them an icon? Here's an example :

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QIcon>
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent) {

    lyt = new QVBoxLayout;
    grpBx = new QGroupBox("Radio buttons");
    QVBoxLayout* lyt_btns = new QVBoxLayout;
    grpBx->setLayout(lyt_btns);
    rBtn1 = new QRadioButton("");
    rBtn2 = new QRadioButton("");
    lyt_btns->addWidget(rBtn1);
    lyt_btns->addWidget(rBtn2);
    rBtn1->setIcon(QIcon(":/spoon.png"));
    rBtn1->setIconSize(QSize(10,10));
    rBtn2->setIcon(QIcon(":/fork.png"));
    rBtn2->setIconSize(QSize(10,10));
    lyt->addWidget(grpBx);

    setLayout(lyt);
}

Widget::~Widget() {
    delete lyt;
    delete rBtn1;
    delete rBtn2;
    delete grpBx;
}
```

[image: Final sample code screenshot]

**PS** if you don't know what is and how to use the Qt ressource system here some tips:

1. Choose the Edit view in Qt Creator.
2. Right-click on the project, then choose Add New.... In the New File dialog that
   opens, click on Qt under Files and Classes, and click on Qt Resource file.
3. Name the file resources.
4. Add it to the current project.
5. If resources.qrc isn't already open in the editor, double-click on it in the
   solution pane. The resource file editor will appear.
6. Click on Add, choose Add prefix, and make the prefix /.
7. Click on Add again, then on Add Files, and choose your icon.

After that you've added ressources to your `.qrc` file, the application can access those files by simply using the colon symbol "`:`" + the prefix specified in *step 6* and then the ressource name (*as shown in the example*)

Please see : [The Qt Resource System documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html)

Comment: I missed the setIcon method. Thanks for reminding me. Regarding the Qt Resource System, I'm not using it on purpose in this project (need to be able to change icons manually via file manager).

Comment: Application resources are best suited for text and small media files, such as icons or images. However, you should avoid using them for larger objects, such as large movies and sounds, because they will unnecessarily increase the binary size of your application. Me voluntarily I would have used the Qt resource system because it is only about icons. But it is up to you to choose ... and you're welcome